# How to apply css to php 'echo $tube->error;'?

Tags: php, html, css, styles, stylesheet

The CSS that I'm attempted to attach to 'echo $tube->error;' is not showing.. It just shows as default black text as if it had no css... How would I fix this?

Thanks (:

Below is what I need to fix..

The html/php part:

```
<div id="error">
        <pre>
        <?php } else {

        echo $tube->error;

        }
    }
        ?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

The html/php part in context:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['url']))
{
  include('curl.php');
  include('youtube.php');

  $tube = new youtube();

  $links = $tube->get($_POST['url']);

  if($links) { ?>

  <div id="result"> 
  <b>Download Links  ( Same IP Downloading only )</b> :
        <?php
        $format = '<p><a href="%3$s">Download</a> video.%s - %s<br/>Right-click download link and choose etc...</p>';
        while($link = array_shift($links))
{
    echo vsprintf($format,$link);
}
        ?>
  </div>
  <div id="error">
        <pre>
        <?php } else {

        echo $tube->error;

        }
    }
        ?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#error {
    width:404px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size:12;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    padding-top:20px;   
}
```

The part of youtube.php(additional info.. not sure if you guys need this):

```
function get($url)
{
    $this->conn = new Curl('youtube');

    $html = $this->conn->get($url);

    if(strstr($html,'verify-age-thumb'))
    {
        $this->error = "Adult Video Detected";
        return false;
    }

    if(strstr($html,'das_captcha'))
    {
        $this->error = "Captcah Found please run on diffrent server";
        return false;
    }

    if(!preg_match('/stream_map=(.[^&]*?)&/i',$html,$match))
    {
        $this->error = "Error Locating Downlod URL's";
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks again for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
    include('curl.php');
    include('youtube.php');

    $tube = new youtube();

    $links = $tube->get($_POST['url']);

    if ($links) {
?>
<div id="result"> 
<b>Download Links  ( Same IP Downloading only )</b> :
<?php
    $format = '<p><a href="%3$s">Download</a> video.%s - %s<br/>Right-click download link and choose etc...</p>';
    while($link = array_shift($links)) {
        echo vsprintf($format,$link);
    }
?>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div id="error">
    <pre>
    <?php echo $tube->error; ?>
    </pre>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Don't forget to include the CSS... and please, please write more readable in the future.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I was wrong, it wasn't a CSS error, but a construct error, as others have noticed. I just rewrote the "The html/php part in context" to make it more clear and hopefully working:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['url']))
{
  include('curl.php');
  include('youtube.php');

  $tube = new youtube();

  $links = $tube->get($_POST['url']);

  if($links) 
  { 
    ?>
    <div id="result"> 
      <b>Download Links  ( Same IP Downloading only )</b> :
      <?php
      $format = '<p><a href="%3$s">Download</a> video.%s - %s<br/>Right-click download link and choose etc...</p>';
      while($link = array_shift($links))
      {
        echo vsprintf($format,$link);
      }
      ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
  } 
  else 
  {
    ?>
    <div id="error">
      <pre>
      <?php echo $tube->error; ?>
      </pre>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Hope everything is ok now :)

Comment: All of my other css is working. The only time it doesn't work for me is  when i try to apply css to ' <?php } else {

    echo $tube->error;

    }
}
    ?>' Any ideas?

Comment: I rewrote answer, it wasn't  css-thing..see if it works now :)

Comment: DragonWork submitted a fix moments ago. Yours worked also, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Your `<div id="error">` is never rendered if there is an error, because your `else` statement only includes the error text itself. Move the `div` and `pre` inside the `else` to get it working.

```
<?php } else { ?>
  <div id="error">
    <pre>
       <?php echo $tube->error; ?>    
    </pre>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Im not sure if I understand. Do you mean this?: <pre>
    <?php } else {
      <div id="error">
     <pre>
       echo $tube->error;
        </pre>
        </div>
    }
 }
  ?> ..? This gives me HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @henrymb67: You actually should restructure your whole code, as there are quite a few other errors too. Such as `</pre></div>` in the end getting rendered whether `$_POST['url']` is set or not. Try to use proper indentation to keep code readable so you can keep track of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
#error pre {
    width:404px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size:12;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    padding-top:20px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your CSS also for `#error pre` and not only `#error`:

```
div#error {
    width:404px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top:20px;   
}

div#error pre
{
    font-size:12;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    color:white;
}
```

Use also an inspector (like Chrome's one, that you call with CTRL+I) to make sure:
- there are not overrides that undo there lines
- CSS is properly loaded (if in an external file)